# Forming IPAddresses from Text file

Tags: perl, sed, regex, text-processing

I have a huge text file that contains IP addresses scrambled all over but not in one unit

for example.

So what the@192@ heck are you doing@168@ in my house @10@.you were not @16@ supposed to be here.

What I want is to make an output file and in that make ipadresses file like following

```
    1.192.168.10.16
    2.192.223.22.44
    etc..
```

I have good understanding of regular expressions and can extract specific information from a text file but here I need to combine these that where I got confused.How should one approach problem like that? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please give a more complete example. Are the number that make up the IPs _always_ delimited by `@`? Can you have an IP spread out across multiple lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of, assuming that the numbers you want are always delimited by `@` symbols, is:

```
$ grep -oP '@\K\d+' file | perl -pe '$. % 4 != 0 && s/\n/./;'
192.168.10.16
192.169.10.16
192.128.10.16
192.162.10.16
```

This does not number the lines though, so to add them do

```
$ grep -oP '@\K\d+' file | perl -pe '$. % 4 != 0 && s/\n/./;' | perl -pe 's/^/$.. /'
1. 192.168.10.16
2. 192.169.10.16
3. 192.128.10.16
4. 192.162.10.16
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -oP '@\K\d+' file` : `-o` means "print only the matching part of the line" and `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) for `grep`. This lets us use the `\d` to match numbers and, most importantly, the `\K` which means "forget whatever you matched before me". The `\K` lets me grep for `@\K10` and only print the `10` because the `@` is before the `\K`.
- `perl -pe` : read the input file line by line, apply the script given by `-e` to each line and then print that line (`-p`).
- `'$. % 4 != 0 && s/\n/./;` : `%` is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), `$.` is the current line number of the input file. This code will substitute a newline charatcer (`\n`) with a `.` on lines that are *not* divisible by 4. The result is that since we are feeding it a list of numbers (the output of `grep`), each group of 4 numbers will be printed on the same line since the `\n` was converted to a `.`.
- `perl -pe 's/^/$.. /'` : Just add the current line number to the beginning of each line.

---

Steeldriver [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446994/forming-ipaddresses-from-text-file/447027#comment586330_447027) a very nice alternative:

```
grep -oP '@\K\d+' file | xargs -n4 printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' | cat -n
```

Which made me think of this one:

```
printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' $(grep -oP '@\K\d+' file ) | cat -n
```

---

If you like, you can do the whole thing in Perl and avoid pipes but I would use the method above. Anyway, always assuming that your numbers are surrounded by `@`, this will also work:

```
perl -ne 'push @f,(/@(\d+)@/g); 
          END{
            $k=1;
            for($i=0;$i<=$#f;$i+=4){
                print "$k. " . join(".",@f[$i..($i+3)]) . "\n"; $k++}
            }' file
```

You can paste that directly into your terminal, just change `file` for the actual file name. The output looks like this:

```
1. 192.168.10.16
2. 192.169.10.16
3. 192.128.10.16
4. 192.162.10.16
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -ne` : read the input file line by line (`-n`) and apply the script given by `-e`.
- `push @f,(/@(\d+)@/g);` : Save each number surrounded by `@` as an element of the `@f` array.
- `END{}` : do this after you have finished processing all lines
- `for($i=0;$i<=$#f;$i+=4){}` : iterate through the array. Since IPs have 4 sets of numbers, we read the array in jumps of four.
- `join(".",@f[$i..($i+3)])` : This connects the 4 elements of the array with `.` for printing.
- The `$k` is just to print the numbers in front of the IPs.

---

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know about \K (was trying to do something similar using perl lookarounds). I did find an alternative for the modulo counting though - using xargs e.g. `grep -oP '@\K\d+' file | xargs -n4 printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n'`. One could pipe through `cat -n` for the numbering.

Comment: @steeldriver ooh, that printf is clever! Not at my computer at the moment but unless you want to post an answer yourself, I'll modify mine to include those suggestions. Assuming you don't mind of course.

Comment: Sure no problem! I wish I could figure out a way to do the counting natively as well...

Comment: @steeldriver done, thanks. I also thought of an even shorter one: `printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' $(grep -oP '@\K\d+' file ) | cat -n`.

Comment: @terdon Please explain a little bit more and easy to understand the following expression  '$. % 4 != 0 && s/\n/./;

Comment: @khan the modulo operator returns what's left when you divide X by Y. So, `6 % 4 = 2` since if you divide 6 by 4, you will have 2 left over. The `$.` is the current line number, which means that when `$. % 4` is 0, this particular line number is a multiple of 4 (4,8,12,16 etc). The construct could be written as `if ( $. % 4 != 0){s/\n/./}` which means `if the current line number is not a multiple of 4, then replace new lines with '.'`. The result of this is that the new lines are converted to dots on all lines that are not multiples of 4.

Comment: @khan Feel free to @ ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if you need more details.

Comment: This is one well written answer!

Answer (score 3):

**Using GNU `sed`**

You could also use `sed` for this purpose.Assuming the numbers in the ipaddress are present in-between `@@` symbols.

```
$ sed 's/.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g' file
192.168.10.16
192.169.10.16
192.128.10.16
192.162.10.16
```

Below command puts the number in an order before the fetched ip-addresses,

```
$ sed 's/.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g' file | awk '{ print NR". "$0}'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'So what the@192@ heck are you doing@168@ in my house @10@.you were not @16@ supposed to be here.' | sed 's/.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g' | awk '{ print NR". "$0}'
1. 192.168.10.16
```

#### [Please Explain your code a bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446994/forming-ipaddresses-from-text-file/463778?noredirect=1#comment613116_463778)

```
sed 's/.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g' file | awk '{ print NR". "$0}'
|                                                                   |   |                     |
|                                                                   |   |                     |
|<----------------------First part--------------------------------->|   |<-----Second part--->|
```

OP mentioned that  Ip addresses are scrambled(spreaded) all over the file with each part of an ipaddress is enclosed within `@@` and each line contains four `@...@` parts. So he wants  to fetch  all the numbers present inside `@@` line by line and prints it in an ip-address format(`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`).

**First Part**

`sed` parses the input file line by line.

Consider the below regex in my code and also the above mentioned example. We have to give the regex that matches the whole line and also it would contain fetching groups in-order to fetch the words according to our criteria, so that the fetched group would be reused through back-reference.

Example line:

```
So what the@192@ heck are you doing@168@ in my house @10@.you were not @16@ supposed to be here.
```

Regex:

```
.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*
```

`.*`

It matches any character 0 or more time except newline character.

`@\(.*\)@`

In `sed`, `()`(fetching groups) this parentheses are used to fetch group of characters or words or numbers. By default sed uses basic regex so we have to escape the parenthesis  inorder to make fetching to work.But if you use sed with `-r`(`extended-regex`) flag, you don't need escaping.

In our case it's `\(.*\)` , both open and close brackets are escaped. On sed reading the whole line,  it stops the matching and starts to fetch all the characters or numbers or anything after the `@` symbol and stops fetching until it finds the next `@` symbol. Then it stores the fetched group in a special buffer called (pattern space). so that fetched characters would be used further. Now sed fetches the numbers between the first `@@` symbols (i,e.192).

`.*`

After catching the first group, `sed` starts to parse the next characters and matches anything 0 or more times.

`@\(.*\)@`

Fetch the numbers between the second `@@` symbols.(i,e 168)

`.*`

Matches any and then it moves on.

`@\(.*\)@`

Fetch the numbers between the third `@@` part.(i.e 10)

`.*`

Matches any and then it moves on.

`@\(.*\)@`

Fetch the numbers between the fourth `@@` part.(i.e 16)

`.*`

There may or may-not be characters present after the fourth `@@` symbols. So we have to give this `.*` in-order to match all the characters after the fourth  `@@` part.

So `sed` fetches the exact numbers we want and stored it in a buffer.

Default Format(syntax) of `sed`,

```
sed 's/regex/replacement/g' file
```

code:

```
sed 's/.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g' file
```

so sed searches for the match of this regex. Once it finds the match, it will be replaced by the replacement part. And `g` global flag helps to replace all the occurrences of regex string with the replacement part.(`g-global`).

In our case,  regex will matches the first line and the whole line would be replaced by our fetched groups `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`. Then sed does this operation on all the lines which matches our regex. In the replacement part the fetched groups are preceeded by `\`. And hence it's called back-referencing. If we fail to separate the groups by `.`(dots),

```
\1\2\3\4
```

the output would be,

```
1921681016
```

So we have to separate the groups with `.`(dots). So that it would appears in an ip-address format.

```
\1.\2.\3.\4
```

Now the output would be,

```
192.168.10.16
```

**Second Part**

```
awk '{ print NR". "$0}'
```

Now the sed output for the first line would be `192.168.10.16`. This output was feded as input to the second `awk` command.

- Awk's `NR`(Number of Records) variable stores the line or record number.Note that, at-last  value of `NR` would be the last line number. Like `sed` , `awk` parses the input file line by line. So `NR` value of 1st line would be 1 and the second line would be `2` and so on.
- In awk's print function, the character would be printed as it is, if it was placed within double quotes. So it prints `.` after the line number(i,e current NR).
- `$0` prints the whole line as it is.

So the output of whole command would be,

```
$ sed 's/.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*@\(.*\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g' file | awk '{ print NR". "$0}'
192.168.10.16
192.169.10.16
192.128.10.16
192.162.10.16
```

---

You may also use this command,

```
sed 's/.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'So what the@192@ heck are you doing@168@ in my house @10@.you were not @16@ supposed to be here.' | sed 's/.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*@\([0-9]\+\)@.*/\1.\2.\3.\4/g'
192.168.10.16
```

Answer (score -1):

There may be a fancy way to do this with terminal, but I don't know how.  Here's how I would do it using python

Copy this code into a new file, name it whatEverYouWant.py and change the line that says 'input.txt' to be 'yourFileWithIps.txt'

```
import re

validIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";

ips = []
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    output = f.read()
    ips = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', output)

for x in range(1, len(ips) + 1):
    print str(x) + '.' + ips[x-1]
```

then from terminal navigate to where you saved whatEverYouWant.py and type

```
python whatEverYouWant.py
```

and that should output what you want.

Results from my own test

```
cam@cam-P5E:~/Desktop$ python getips.py
1.192.168.0.1
2.255.255.255.0
3.10.0.0.1
4.192.192.192.192
```

Comment: My python-fu is very limited but as far as I can tell, your script is looking for actual IPs, as in `123.456.7.8`, but the OP has the component numbers spread out randomly in the file, presumably delineated by `@`. In any case, your script gives no output on the OP's example file.

Comment: I think your regex should incorporate something like `(@(\d{1,3})@.*){4}` (#NOTE untested), viz. 4 groups of two @'s with inbetween 1 to three digits that you select as subgroups.